# GAE python update in database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a question about updating field in GAE database. My problem looks like this:

```
class A(db.Model):
    a = db.StringProperty()
```

and I added bool field:

```
class A(db.Model):
    a = db.StringProperty()
    b = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Now my problem is I'd like to have every instance of model b == False.

To update it I could of course drag them out of datastore and put them back there, but there is 700k elements there already and I really don't know how to do it efficiently. I can't take them out at once because I get soft memory exceeded errors. If I try to do it with little chunks - it costs me many db read operations. Do you have any idea how else I could update my datastore?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @ShayErlichmen.  However, if you really want to update every entity, the easiest way is to use the MapReduce library:
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

It's not as easy as it sounds, because the documentation sucks, but this is the getting started point:
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython

You just write a function foo() that will check the value of each entity passed to it, and if necessary, write update the value of your Boolean, and write it.

The library will grab batches of entities and send each batch to a separate task.  Each task will run in a loop calling your function foo().  Note that the batches run in parallel, so it may launch a few instances in parallel, but it tends to be quick.

Answer (score 1):

You new attribute can be in one of three states: None, False and True. just treat None as False in your code and you won't have todo the update.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really query for that values. They are not None, they are missing  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598605/appengine-query-datastore-for-records-with-missing-value

Edit: I'm trying A.all().filter('b =', None).count() but it gives me 0

Comment: try A.all().filter('b !=', True)

Comment: If those 700k entities were written using the first version of the model class, no query can be written that retrieves only those entities that don't have the b property at all.  Your best bet is the standard answer for schema changes: write a simple map/reduce job.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum Is it because the index doesn't have a reference to old entities? Wouldn't it be cheaper to have a process of reindex rather than update very entity in the datastore?

Comment: Indeed, there is no index that indexes the absence of a property.  There is no reindexing operation built into the datastore -- the datastore doesn't know when you change your schema (since the schema is dynamic) so it cannot do that automatically.  So loading and writing back every entity is the only way.  Of course, you could also just leave them as they are, and write your app to deal with it (but then you have to be careful when querying for this property).