# ndb projection query return incorrect number of entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My TwAccount is

```
class TwAccount(ndb.Model):

   100 different properties here
   error = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
```

I try:

```
twaccount_dbs = model.TwAccount.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('followuserfollowme') == True)
```

it returns 1 entity

But I only want to query 1 property.

```
twaccount_dbs = model.TwAccount.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('followuserfollowme') == True).fetch(projection=["error"])
```

then it returns 0 entity.

I try

```
twaccount_dbs = model.TwAccount.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('followuserfollowme') == True).fetch(projection=[model.TwAccount.error])
```

but it also returns 0 entity

I expect it returns 1 entity.

Update 1:
I figure out that if error is an emtpy (so that does not exist), then the projection query will return 0

My objective is to query all entities in TwAccount. If error is empty, then do deferred.defer(function,entity_key).

I want to use projection query to save the cost of reading. Is it impossible?

Comment: Is your `TwAccount.error` property indexed?

Comment: yes, it is indexed. I updated my question. I figure out that if error is an emtpy (so that does not exist), then the projection query will return 0. My objective is to query all entities in TwAccount. If error is empty, then do deferred.defer(function,entity_key). I want to use projection query to save the cost of reading. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot filter query results by an unset/empty property:

From [Index definition and structure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes#index-definition-structure):

> An entity is included in the index only if it has an indexed value set
>   for every property used in the index; if the index definition refers
>   to a property for which the entity has no value, that entity will not
>   appear in the index and hence will never be returned as a result for
>   any query based on the index.

See also related [AppEngine: Query datastore for records with <missing> value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598605/appengine-query-datastore-for-records-with-missing-value)